# Retrieve data from ajax query

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

So I've got a website where I want to click a button, check to see if the user has certain permissions, and if so popup a window to a new web page.  On the java script I've got something like this:

```
function sendAjax(methodName, dataArray, success, error, category) {
    var error2 = error || function () { };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/PermissionChecker' + methodName,
        data: JSON.stringify(dataArray),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (r, s, x) { if (!success || success(r, s, x) != false) if (typeof (window.ChangeLogAdd) == 'function') { ChangeLogAdd(category); } },
        error: error2
    });
}

function CheckPermissions() {
    sendAjax("CheckPermission", null, function (data) { var permission = eval('(' + data + ')'); if (permission == true) { alert('yay'); } else { alert('nay'); } }, null, 'Check Permission');
}
```

And the C# side is a simple function that does an if check and returns a bool.  The function call goes through fine, but when it returns the bool I get a javascript error "Expected ']'".  I assume this has something to do with my success function:

```
    function (data) { 
        var permission = eval('(' + data + ')'); 
        if (permission == true) { 
            alert('yay'); 
        } 
        else { 
            alert('nay'); 
        } 
    }
```

seeing as I didn't get this error before I tried what I'm doing there, so I was wondering how I would go about getting the data back from the ajax call to make pass the `permission == true` if/else check

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that you're expecting JSON and receiving a boolean.

Comment: Break your functions up into multiple lines. It's hard to help you when everything is so compact. You gain nothing by formatting your code this way, instead you are making it difficult to read. I typically only have one line functions if the function only consists of one line.

Comment: sorry about that, I've edited my question with a less compact version of my success function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use eval for this purpose. It's unsafe and the source of many bugs. Just make the server respond with JSON and use $.getJSON.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example of "responding with JSON and using $.getJSON"? To say that I know what I'm doing with ajax would be an understatement

Comment: If your server responded with `'{"permission":true}'` and you used $.getJSON() instead of $.ajax then your data would be the object `{"permission": true}` and you could just say: `if data.permission`